# Delegate that returns a delegate

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a delegate that will return a delegate. I then want to invoke this delegate, and also invoke the returned inner delegate. My question is: Why is this causing an error? And how to I change this code to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

The error message is 'Method name expected'.

```
delegate string del();
delegate Delegate nestedDel();

public static void main()
{
    nestedDel myNestedDel = () =>
    {
        del myInnerDel = () => { return "inside"; };
        return myInnerDel;
    };

    Delegate k = myNestedDel();

    k(); // Error!!!
}
```

Comment: Try reading the error message.

Comment: Tell us what the error is.  Don't make us wonder and guess.

Comment: `Func<int, string> second;  Func<double, Func<int, string>> first = price => new Func<int, string>(number => $"You pay {price*number} dollars"); second = first(3.50); Console.WriteLine(second(5));`

Comment: Delegates should be type-safe, so avoid Delegate as the return type.  Saves you from having to use DynamicInvoke().  Consider `Func<del> myNestedDel = ...`.  Might as well dump del, favor `Func<Action>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you've messed up the types. One of the delegates should **return the other one**, so its return type should simply be the type of the other delegate. In your code example:

```
delegate string del();
delegate Delegate nestedDel();
```

you are in fact returning a delegate, but `Delegate` or `MulticastDelegate` are just infrastructure base classes and are not invocable directly. By using these classes you're losing information about list of parameters and return values, so simple `call()` operator cannot work. As Lee mentioned in comments, you could do it by `k.DynamicInvoke()` but that's.. overkill. Just use a proper type name instead of `Delegate`.

Working example:

```
delegate string InnerDel();
delegate InnerDel OuterDel();  // this one returns an instance of Inner delegate

public static void Main()
{
    OuterDel myOuterDelegate = () =>
    {
        InnerDel myInnerDel = () => { return "inside"; };
        return myInnerDel;
    };

    InnerDel k = myOuterDelegate();

    k();
}
```

Personally, I like Func/Actions more than defining my own delegate classes... at least as long as they have at most few parameters. In terms of func/action it would look like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Func<Func<string>> myOuterDelegate = () =>
    {
        Func<string> myInnerDel = () => { return "inside"; };
        return myInnerDel;
    };

    var k = myOuterDelegate();

    k();
}
```

or even..

```
public static void Main()
{
    Func<Func<string>> myOuterDelegate = () => () => { return "inside"; };

    var k = myOuterDelegate();

    k();
}
```

Comment: This will work but the code in the OP does return a delegate. The error is that `Delegate` instances cannot be invoked using `()` but must use `DynamicInvoke` to call them dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because instances of the `Delegate` type cannot be invoked with the function call syntax i.e. as `k();`.

You can call it using `DynamicInvoke`:

```
string s = (string)k.DynamicInvoke();
```

obviously this is prone to runtime errors so a better approach would be to change the return type of `nestedDel` e.g.

```
delegate Func<string> nestedDel();

nestedDel myNestedDel = () =>
{
    Func<string> myInnerDel = () => { return "inside"; };
    return myInnerDel;
};

stringk = myNestedDel();
```